# Qt Graphics canvas for huge numbers of objects?

Tags: qt, graphics

I have two projects right now that are using Qt as a widget toolkit, and both deal with (what I would call) large amounts of data (easily over 10,000,000 data elements) that need to be rendered interactively. Each `data element' would, ideally, be rendered using about three to five primitives (lines/rects/circles etc.); so a total of probably 40,000,000 graphics primitives.

I've tried the obvious QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene approach, but those classes start to slow down unacceptably at around 400,000 elements. Last time I ran into this problem (for a more modest 1,000,000 primitives) I implemented a graphics canvas manually for Qt. It was a touch buggy (at least one off-by-one error with rendering I was unable to fix . . .), and relies on some other (poorly-written, buggy) code that I don't want to pull into my current projects.

So, my question for the world: is there a (preferably open-source) Qt graphics canvas out there that can handle these kinds of loads? Or am I better off writing one tailored to my specific needs?

Thanks.

Comment: How many will ever be displayed at once?

Comment: Out of these 1,000,000 elements, how many of them are visually unique? With proper pixmap caching and scene indexing method you should be able to handle this. Is each one of your items a QGraphicsItem instead of a QGraphicsObject? Also how many items are visible at a given time? Take a look at the level of detail graphicsview examples on how to optimize that way.

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention two important points. 1: Ideally, all elements should be visible at one time, but this isn't reasonable, so say 10-30%. 2: all graphics are vector graphics . . . I'll take a look at the LoD QGraphicsView examples, thanks @Chris.

Comment: Also: most of the elements will be of same basic shapes (probably 20-25 shapes) but will be coloured differently.

Comment: `QGraphicsScene` uses a BSP tree for spatial partitioning.  You can tweak the max depth of it, and with scenes of your size, can have a massive effect on performance.